# Destructuring possible null values within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, object-destructuring, nullish-coalescing

Is there a better way to handle `null` values within the example below. In entries 5, 7, and 10; a `null` value is present.

The following errors are presented whether the value is `null` or `undefined`.

```
#5  - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
#7  - Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
#10 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, children: [{ id: 'A' }] }, /*  1 */
  { id: 2, children: [{ id: 'B' }] }, /*  2 */
  { id: 3, children: [{ id: 'C' }] }, /*  3 */
  { id: 4, children: [{ }] },         /*  4 */
  //{ id: 5, children: [null] },      /*  5 */
  { id: 6, children: [] },            /*  6 */
  //{ id: 7, children: null },        /*  7 */
  { id: 8 },                          /*  8 */
  { },                                /*  9 */
  //null                              /* 10 */
];

const ids = data.map(
  ({
    id = -1,
    children: [
      {
        id: childId = -1
      } = {}
    ] = []
  } = {}) =>
    ({ id, childId })
);

console.log(ids);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

The following works, but it is less elegant. It requires the use of [nullish-coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operators (or [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operators), [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), and multiple assignments.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, children: [{ id: 'A' }] }, /*  1 */
  { id: 2, children: [{ id: 'B' }] }, /*  2 */
  { id: 3, children: [{ id: 'C' }] }, /*  3 */
  { id: 4, children: [{}] },          /*  4 */
  { id: 5, children: [null] },        /*  5 */
  { id: 6, children: [] },            /*  6 */
  { id: 7, children: null },          /*  7 */
  { id: 8 },                          /*  8 */
  { },                                /*  9 */
  null                                /* 10 */
];

const ids = data.map(item => {
  const
    ref = item ?? {},
    children = ref.children ?? [],
    child = children[0] ?? {};
  return {
    id: ref?.id ?? -1,
    childId: child?.id ?? -1
  };
});

console.log(ids);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I could rewrite this as a nested [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), but it is more difficult to follow... As you can see, I avoided using default parameter values, because you can only destructure `undefined` values. The value `null` is valid, so I have to use a logical OR (a nullish-coalescing operation would work too) to determine the alternative.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, children: [{ id: 'A' }] },  /*  1       */
  { id: 2, children: [{ id: 'B' }] },  /*  2       */
  { id: 3, children: [{ id: 'C' }] },  /*  3       */
  { id: 4, children: [{ id: null }] }, /*  4 (NEW) */
  { id: 5, children: [{}] },           /*  5       */
  { id: 6, children: [null] },         /*  6       */
  { id: 7, children: [] },             /*  7       */
  { id: 8, children: null },           /*  8       */
  { id: 9 },                           /*  9       */
  { },                                 /* 10       */
  null                                 /* 11       */
];

const ids = data.map(item =>
  (ref =>
    ((id, children) =>
      (child =>
        ((childId) =>
          ({ id, childId }))
        (child.id || -1))
      (children[0] || {}))
    (ref.id || -1, ref.children || []))
  (item || {}));

console.log(ids);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do away with the multiple assignments. I don't see any issues with using nullish coalescing and optional chaining.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, children: [{ id: 'A' }] },  /*  1       */
  { id: 2, children: [{ id: 'B' }] },  /*  2       */
  { id: 3, children: [{ id: 'C' }] },  /*  3       */
  { id: 4, children: [{ id: null }] }, /*  4 (NEW) */
  { id: 5, children: [{}] },           /*  5       */
  { id: 6, children: [null] },         /*  6       */
  { id: 7, children: [] },             /*  7       */
  { id: 8, children: null },           /*  8       */
  { id: 9 },                           /*  9       */
  { },                                 /* 10       */
  null                                 /* 11       */
];

const ids = data.map(item => ({
    id: item?.id ?? -1,
    childId: item?.children?.[0]?.id ?? -1
}));

console.log(ids);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Could be me, but I think this is actually *a lot more* readable than any of the variants in the question